# Php Echo in MySQL after Echo For IF Else Statement

Tags: php, mysql

The last block of code is my issue. I want a user to be able to see a different style of link depending on what page they're on. The link would be an if else statement from the SQL table itself. Now the biggest issue is the fact that I'm already using an echo variable to pull the link so I'm not sure how to reinitiate an if else inside of the SQL table itself.

```
<?php   
    $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM navigation WHERE enabled='1');
            while ($row=
            mysql_fetch_array($result))
                {

                echo $row['link'];

                }
?>
```

What I would like to display is something along the lines of

```
<?php   
    $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM navigation WHERE enabled='1' AND permissions >'1'");
            while ($row=
            mysql_fetch_array($result))
                {

                echo $row['link'];

                }
```

My Variable for Enabled is 1, so that if the variable is set to 0 the page is then disabled. After this it searches for your user permissions using

```
if ($admin != null)//Is Guest
if ($admin->get_permissions()==3)//Is Admin
elseif ($admin->get_permissions()==2)//Is VIP User
elseif ($admin->get_permissions()==1)//Is Registered User
```

I want the link to only appear to a user based off of it's registration status, but my biggest problem lies here. I want my user to see the navigation in a certain manner depending on what page they are, but the SQL table is already being queried and is imported as a variable already, so how would I have it display along the lines of

```
<?php
if (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'index.php')){
     echo '<p><a href="index.php" class="active">Home</a></p>';
}
else{
     echo '<p><a href="index.php">Index</a></p>';//<-Note the removed class index in this link
}
```

Sorry if it's hard to understand what I'm saying; tried to word it to the best of my ability.

Comment: I have no clue what this is supposed to be asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried NOT combining the query and doing something along the lines of:

```
<?php
    $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM navigation WHERE enabled='1'");
    if ($result){
        while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            switch($row['permission']){
                //obv not real html tags!!!
                case 1: echo "<reg>".$row['link']."</reg>"; break; 
                case 2: echo "<vip>".$row['link']."</vip>"; break; 
                case 3: echo "<admin>".$row['link']."</admin>"; break;
                default: echo "<blank>no link</blank>"; break;
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Honestly; I didn't even consider the idea. I'll be trying that without a doubt as I see that working.

Comment: You can use ORDER BY in the SQl to spit them out in the right order you want based on index in sql table - i do a kind of maj_index min_index thing in my tables. Word!

Comment: I'll give it a go tonight when I get back to that part. (Didn't like the old site, so redoing from scratch.)